# working as servlet but not as java class. why?

Tags: java, servlets, metadata, saml

I am working on SAML SSO Authentication. 
I have created a servlet to generate SAML metadata and i deployed it and run it and I got the output. 
Same time I have created a java class to generate SAML Metadata with the same code and tried to run it independently. I have added the same Jar files that I have used for that servlet application.
But I got the Exception given below. Can anybody help me to find the difference between running an application independently and by using java servlet??
Thanks in advance.

Exception:

[image: Click here to see the Exception]

Comment: can you post code snippet ?

Comment: have you added the slf4j jars to your standalone program? It seems that it is being used for logging.

Comment: Seems you have different classpaths here. You have a different logback library here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running as servlet in a web container means all sorts of stuff is on the classpath that is automatically provided by the servlet container.

Running using main() means you have to put all needed stuff on the classpath yourself.  The ClassNotFoundException you got should be clear enough in that respect.

(Pls note that although I did say "the" classpath, in a servlet container things are typically not quite that simple.  But that's not the point.  Also note that running as a servlet, and using features of libraries provided for the container, may even mean your stuff *cannot* run as an independent java program simply because the library stuff was deliberately intended for servlet container use exclusively.)

Comment: I have added exactly the same jar files that i used in the web application.
Other than just adding these jar files, how will i configure the class path for the standalone application. Please advice.

Comment: And browsing the contents of those jars you said you added, you can find the org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter.class file ?